# assign values to object properties dynamically

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object with properties ct1 - ct5. The object is an auto-generated linq-to-sql object. I would like to assign values to these properties in c#. Is there any way to do this in a for loop?

e.g. something like (object name: new_condition):

```
for (int i = 1; tag <= 5; i++)
{
   new_condition.cti = values[i];
}
```

where the `i` in cti gets evaluated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only via Reflection, I'm afraid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using reflection. For instance, supose you have a class `A` like this:

```
class A
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }
    public int P2 { get; set; }
    public int P3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can do it like in this simple console sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1,3))
    {
        a.GetType().GetProperty("P" + i).SetValue(a, i, null);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("P1 = {0}",a.P1);
    Console.WriteLine("P2 = {0}",a.P2);
    Console.WriteLine("P3 = {0}",a.P3);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output will be:

```
P1 = 1
P2 = 2
P3 = 3
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer. I think I will be using this solution. Can you perhaps expand on why reflection is the only solution. Is it simply because the GetProperty() method takes a string argument and so can be used dynamically like this or is there something about reflection that lends itself to this particular situation?

Comment: Reflection isn't the only option, but in this case it's the better option.

Comment: Ok but why is it the better option?

Comment: See my answer for the other option. It's a better option because although it's slower and not type safe, it's simpler than my solution. If you can deal with a little more complexity but gain a little type safety and performance, use my answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "type safe"? Is reflection, in general, slow performance-wise?

Comment: The reflection it a little bit more slow, but I think it is not a big problem in this case (a lot of popular libraries use Reflection for many things). By the other hand, the brz's solution is a possible option, the only bad thing is that you need to map each property using a dictionary, I think it is a little more complex and also is not to much safe: if the dictionary index is not found an exception will be thrown.... but like I already said, it is a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Beside reflection as already suggested, you can create a `Dictionary<string,Action<T>>` that does the assignment for you. Something like this:

```
public static int a0;
public static int a1;
public static int a2;

public static Dictionary<string, Action<int>> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>> { 
{"a0", val => a0 = val}, {"a1", val => a1 = val}, {"a2", val => a2 = val }};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        actions["a" + i](i * 2);

    Console.WriteLine(a0);
    Console.WriteLine(a1);
    Console.WriteLine(a2);
}
```